# Setting aspects with OpenCMIS for Alfresco

Tags: groovy, alfresco, cmis, opencmis

I'm trying to use the Alfresco OpenCMIS Extension for aspects in a Groovy script.

I'd like to be able to set an aspect on a document, but when I try to cast a Document as AlfrescoDocument, it throws an error.  I'm pointing Groovy to the Alfresco Chemistry jar files that ship with Alfresco 4.1.5

I can create a document and look at the properties of it, but when I try to convert it to an AlfrescoDocument, it throws an error.

```
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.*
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.data.*
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.*
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.*
import org.alfresco.cmis.client.*;
import org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.*;

def doc = (Document) session.getObject(id);
def adoc = (AlfrescoDocument) doc;
```

.

```
Caught: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object   'org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.DocumentImpl@3e0339' with class  'org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.DocumentImpl' to class 'org.alfresco.cmis.client.AlfrescoDocument'
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object  'org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.DocumentImpl@3e0339' with class 'org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.DocumentImpl' to class 'org.alfresco.cmis.client.AlfrescoDocument'
```

Comment: Does this help? http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/problem-custom-aspects-cmis-policy-06012011-0730 (first Google hit for "alfresco documentimpl alfrescodocument")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.
The session needs to be wired to be able to use the Alfresco Extension:

```
parameter.put(SessionParameter.OBJECT_FACTORY_CLASS, "org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.AlfrescoObjectFactoryImpl");
```

Comment: So my comment linked you straight to the answer?

Comment: Actually no.  That page didn't have that.